# How to setup Lumen in Travis CI

Tags: laravel, travis-ci, lumen

I have been trying to setup a Lumen application in Travis CI and i have found the following problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Dotenv: Environment file .env not found or not readable.
```

Given that this is triggered on `phpunit` execution i'm trying to load my environment variables from my `phpunit.xml` instead of a `.env` file but i don't know how to make it work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your .env file should not be checked into source control and as such you dont want to use it to run builds and on production. Therefore take advantage of using Travis CI to set env variables. Refer to https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/.

Answer (score 1):

`Dotenv` was developed to be used on development environments only. It always expects `.env` to exist and will throw an error if it doesn't.

One workaround is to check for `.env` and only then load `Dotenv`. Here's a sample piece of code that you can use.

```
$dotenv_var = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
if(file_exists(".env")) {
    $dotenv_var->load();
}
```

You can read up more on this issue [here](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/63).